# JS Invalid left-hand side expression in postfix operation?

Tags: javascript

I am playing with a javascript and am running into an error.  The error is this:

Invalid left-hand side expression in postfix operation.

And the script is long but I think this is this issue.  The weird thing is this works when I run it locally, but when it is packaged, using asset_packager, it fails.

Any ideas why I might be getting this error?

**UPDATE:** After doing more research I found this function.  The error seems to happen after in the "while" statement and I assume it's the "++ + a + ".  This is a plugin so I didn't want to go messing with the code...but do you thing this could be it?

```
m.getInternetExplorerMajorVersion = function() {
            var a = m.getInternetExplorerMajorVersion.cached = typeof m.getInternetExplorerMajorVersion.cached != "undefined" ? m.getInternetExplorerMajorVersion.cached : function() {
                var a = 3, b = d.createElement("div"), c = b.getElementsByTagName("i");
                while ((b.innerHTML = "<!--[if gt IE "++ + a + "]><i></i><![endif]-->") && c[0])
Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side expression in postfix operation
                    ;
                return a > 4 ? a : !1
            }();
            return a
        }
```

Comment: This code works perfectly. I think the error is in another part of the code

Comment: What is on the line the error is reported on?

Comment: Why are you passing `undefined` as a parameter?

Comment: Is that what would cause something like that?

Comment: `Math.round((964 - wid) / 2)`=`Math.round((964 - wid) / 2)`+'px'

Comment: What if you try `this.centerStack(id)` instead of `Stacks.centerStack(id)`?

Answer (score 23):

You didn't say which plugin was that but I was dealing with the same problem, Jeffrey, with I think the same plugin, because my code was looking almost the same.

I followed your lead. The plugin was History.js, from page:
https://github.com/browserstate/History.js/ and I was using bundled html4+html5 version, which was minimized.

I changed that fragment

```
innerHTML="<!--[if gt IE "+ ++a+"]><i></i><![endif]-->"
```

into

```
innerHTML="<!--[if gt IE "+ (++a)+"]><i></i><![endif]-->"
```

And it did the job!

I started to wonder what exactly problem lied in. The most important suspect was of course minification "compression". In normal situation following code is correct

```
var a=0; "begining of string "+ ++a+" the rest of string";
```

And returns `"begining of string 1 the rest of string"`

However the minification gets rid of white space and turns it into something that is understood by a browser as a:

```
var a=0;"begining of string "+++a+" the rest of string";
```

What gives us error `Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side expression in postfix operation`

EDIT: As [Sam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/822138/sam) pointed out, the issue was caused by minifcation, and not than gzip compression, of course :)

Comment: Had the same problem with History.js and using WP Minify plugin for wordpress. Thanks very much!

Comment: You must mean JS minification, **not** gzip compression.

Comment: @sam I guess both methods can cause the same issue. In my case it was gzip ;)

Comment: Had this same exact problem with jQuery form validator - could see the error in Chrome, could see the snippet in sources. So, thanks.

Comment: I used this solution to resolve errors when I used Java Jawr to minify jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js.

Comment: Just for reference, I just used this solution, I found this problem with jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js in a CMS that automatically compiles and minifies all the assets, the culprit code was `this.id="ui-id-"+ ++t`. Firefox reports the error as "SyntaxError: invalid increment/decrement operand"

Answer (score 9):

This error is in reference to a `++` or `--` following a non reference, such as a returned value. The problem is somewhere else in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Before the increment always the variable to be incremented in calibraces

```html
 existingPost ? existingPost.reactions[reaction]++ : ""
```